# Maven SNAPSHOT for WAR projects too?

Tags: maven, jar, versioning, war, snapshot

I'm using the Maven's 'SNAPSHOT' feature for my JAR projects. I want to keep everything consistent, in terms of versioning, but: does it make sense to use this feature for WAR projects as well? Should I use this:

```
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

or this?

```
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't?You can use SNAPSHOT in whatever project you want as long as it means that your application is under development.